# Read settings from App.Config using C#

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2012, console-application, app-config

This is my app config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

<appSettings>
    <add key="Testit" value="7777"/>
</appSettings>

...

</configuration>
```

I am using console application in C#

```
Console.WriteLine(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Testit"]);
```

I get this error:

- ConfigurationErrorsException was unhandled I know that I could put try catch there but that is not necessary

If I move appSettings tag around app.config it complains that the placement is incorrect so right now it is placed correctly. I have no idea what else to try to display that value from app.config.

Also maybe this will help my project is .NET Framework 4.0 using C# and it is a console application with App.Config <- this is where I am reading value from.

This is the inner exception:

{"Only one  element allowed per config file and if present must be the first child of the root  element. (C:\...\Program.vshost.exe.Config line 8)"}

And I only have ONE configSection!!!

Update:

Do I need to enclose appSettings into another tag???????

Comment: Please post the entire exception.  Just telling us the type of the exception (ConfigurationErrorsException) is not enough.

Comment: Post the stack trace for the exception.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the ConfigurationManager class instead of ConfigurationSettings class

Comment: Can't Visual Studio says expecting ? it has to be like this <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: Sorry ignore that ? Suggestion.. It is valid XML.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it and it works fine.

```
Console.WriteLine(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Testit"].ToString());

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="Testit" value="7777"/>
</appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: so you think it will work on his sytem as well??

Comment: Failed for me again. Maybe I am missing Using statement I have using System.Configuration; do I need any others. Also your method says it is obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

appSettings is most likely defined a second time later in your app.config

Comment: Defined only once. In fact all the tags in my app.cofig defined once.

Answer (score 0):

OH wow found a solution, I guess this must be the Microsoft logic :)

so I switched the order of appSettings inside the App.Config file before it was:

```
<appSetting>
...
</appSetting>
<configSection>
...
</configSection>
```

now it is

```
<configSection>
...
</configSection>
<appSetting>
...
</appSetting>
```

It works.